# Why does a fetch request causes server to return 403 while XMLHttpRequest does not?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I made `XMLHttpRequest` get a json value from a server using this code:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    let msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    // Send the request to our POST Servlet
  }
};

xhr.open("GET", "/libs/granite/csrf/token.json", true);
xhr.send();
```

However, I want to use `fetch` in my code, however, upon trying the code below, I was instantly answered with a 403 error:

```
fetch("/libs/granite/csrf/token.json", { method: "GET" })
.then((response: any) => {
  if (response.status === 200 || response.statusText === "OK") {
    callback(ResponseCode.SUCCESS);
  } else {
    callback(ResponseCode.ERROR);
  }
})
.catch((error: any) => {
  callback(ResponseCode.ERROR);
});
```

I want to know the difference between the two and what should I modify to make the `fetch` work.

Comment: We can't see the server side code that determines what the status of the response should be. If you want to see the difference between the requests, look at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: @Quentin I looked through the network tab and the only difference I saw was their type, one is xhr and the other was, well, fetch.

Answer (score 5):

If there is credential validation on the server side then it could be failing because fetch does not send or receive cookies. You'll have to do -

```
credentials:'include'
```

Within your fetch request, as per the mozilla documents on Fetch

> By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server,
>   resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on
>   maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials header
>   must be sent).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch